# ColorAnimation with subtractive By property

Tags: wpf, templates, templatebinding, coloranimation

How to make WPF subtract By property from Template binded background?

I want to animate my background of button's template using "By" property. It works correctly if i need to make background lighter, because "By" adds up with "back color". But actually I want to make it darker, and I don't know how to make WPF subtract By property from Template binded background.

```
<Border x:Name="BackRect" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="0" Height="115" Width="215">
                <ContentControl x:Name="MainTitle"
                            FontFamily="Inter"    
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>

<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard> 
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty=(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        By="#A0A0A0" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0:0:0.3" >
                            <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <SineEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                            </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Try using `From` and `To` instead of `By`.

Comment: the background color can be different, so I want to use the relative By property

Comment: You can't specify a negative color to the `By` property.

Comment: Just use some math to figure out what your `To` color should be.

Comment: Ok, what a better way to convert To value in your opinion.

Comment: Well, get your original background color, subtract your "By" color, and use the result as your `To` value.

Comment: You may draw the element on top of a black (or otherwise "dark") area and animate its Opacity.

Comment: Oh, it's the interesting think, fnx

Comment: Well, "*you can't specify a negative color to the By property*" is actually not true. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, despite apparently not mentioned in the documentation, you can use negative values for the `ScA`, `ScR`, `ScG` and `ScB` properties of the Color struct, so that you can get a subtracted Color by means of a ColorAnimation's `By` property.

Here is an example:

```
<Rectangle Width="300" Height="200">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="AnimateFillColor">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                        Duration="0:0:0.2">
                        <ColorAnimation.By>
                            <Color ScR="-0.5"/>
                        </ColorAnimation.By>
                    </ColorAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="AnimateFillColor"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```